# Response Surface Methodology using Moving Least Squares Method

Tags: optimization, approximation, surfaces, mathematical-modeling, least-squares

I would like to obtain the response surface of a mathematical function for reliability-based design optimization (RBDO). To obtain a reliably response surface, I learned that moving least squares method (MLSM) is the better option than the conventional least squares method. Therefore, I am strictly following [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045794903004309) article to implement MLSM on Matlab for RBDO.

Say I use the Rosenbrock function:$$f\left ( x_{1}, x_{2} \right ) = 100 \left ( x_{1}^{2}- x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left ( 1- x_{1} \right)^{2}$$ as my test function to obtain the response surface using MLSM before I implement into the RBDO framework. The range of both variables are $-2\leq x_{1}\leq2$ and $-2\leq x_{2}\leq2$ respectively.

A conventional least squares method follows: $$b\left (x \right )=\left [X ^{T}X\right ]^{-1}X^{T}Y$$

This is what I obtained after implementing RSM using least squares method and sampled using central composite design (CCD):
[image]

In MLSM however, a weighing matrix $W(x)$ is introduced, which gives:
 $$b\left (x \right )=\left [X ^{T}W\left (x \right )X\right ]^{-1}X^{T}W\left (x \right )Y$$

I would like to use 4-th order polynomial $w(\frac{x-x_{n}}{R})=1-6(\frac{x-x_{n}}{R})^{2}+8(\frac{x-x_{n}}{R})^{3}-3(\frac{x-x_{n}}{R})^{4}$ as the weighing function, where:

$$W\left (x \right )=\begin{bmatrix}
w\left (\frac{x-x_{1}}{R} \right ) & 0 & ... & 0\\ 
0 & w\left (\frac{x-x_{2}}{R} \right ) & ... & 0\\ 
: & : & ... & :\\ 
0 & 0 & ... & w\left (\frac{x-x_{n}}{R} \right )
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that MLSM is a local approximation and not global. Now, I am confused with 2 things here:

1. How many design samples do I take?
2. If I follow the CCD and apply the weight function, don't the sample points on the edge and outside CCD have $0$ weightage?
3. Or shall i just use Latin hypercube sampling (LHS) instead of CCD?

I'd be very thankful if someone could help with a simple example to implement MLSM to obtain response surface. You may use Rosenbrock function as a test function and all the other information above above for the example.

Comment: Some help with the context would be welcome. What are the measurements? How are they distributed? You kindly posted your matrices, and some details in how to construct them would be nice.